# Mac OS X 10.7 Window Shadow Params

Tags: macos, mac

I would like to create some Mac OS X 10.7 Windows "simulations" in Photoshop.

I would like to learn about the window's shadow parameters, like size, spread and distance.

Could anybody help me with this???

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying to simulate.

Comment: Are you just asking about shadows? Or is there something more?

Comment: I am not trying to simulate Windows, I am trying to simulate Mac OS shadows

Comment: @bassplayer7 I am talking just about the shadows, I already have made the rest of the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac OS X standard windows use drop shadow with folowing parameters: black #000000 color with opacity 60%, angle 90º, distance 25px, size 50px, spread 0px.

Comment: As of the latest OS X release I believe 50% opacity, 22px distance, and 45px size more closely approximate the drop shadow. For retina displays, 45px distance and 90px size.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's more of a combination of two drop shadows. These settings work well for me in direct comparison to the original shadow:

- Dropshadow 1:

  - Opacity: 47%
  - Angle: 90°
  - Distance: 26px
  - Spread: 0px
  - Size: 43px
- Dropshadow 2:

  - Opacity: 44%
  - Angle: 90°
  - Distance: 0px
  - Spread: 0px
  - Size: 3px

The second drop shadow is for the fine darker line you notice around every window, especially when examining OS X window chrome on white background.

Answer (score 2):

```
.box { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #e4e4e4; border: 1px solid #adadad;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

<div class="box">
 Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2020, the official [Apple UI Design Resources for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/#macos-apps) tells us this:

- 1px inside white 15% opacity border
- 0.5px outside black 65% opacity border
- 18px top offset 50 blur black 52% opacity shadow

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Revolter/sg352ozv/

*(Insert > Apple macOS UI > Windows > Window with Titlebar > Dark Aqua)*